# c++ closure with unexpected result

Tags: c++, lambda, closures

I'm testing some features regarding to  closures, but I run into some issues, here's some code, there's a vector of 3 lambda functions, these functions captures the local variable inside BuildFns , all the i's memory location are the same, but , only the first call from the main function actually output 3, should we expect all of the functions inside the vector output 3 when we invoke them in main?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
auto BuildFns() {
  vector<function<void()>> vec;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cout << &i << '\n';
    vec.push_back([&i]() {
      cout << i << endl;
      cout << &i << '\n';
    });
  }
  return vec;
}


auto main() -> int {
  auto vec = BuildFns();
  vec[0]();
  vec[1]();
  vec[2]();
}
```

output:

```
0x7ffeedfa25c8
0x7ffeedfa25c8
0x7ffeedfa25c8
3
0x7ffeedfa25c8
-1581316512  // what's wrong with this i? isn't it contained in the closure environment and can't be written if it's still been accessed?
0x7ffeedfa25c8
-1581316512
0x7ffeedfa25c8
```

expected:

```
0xaddress_of_i
0xaddress_of_i
0xaddress_of_i
3
0xaddress_of_i
3
0xaddress_of_i
3
0xaddress_of_i
```

Comment: The variable `i` is local inside the loop only. Once the loop is finished the variable goes out of scope and its life-time ends, and any pointer or reference to it will be dangling and invalid. Using that reference leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok, I thought the closure will extend i's lifetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are doing a capture by reference (`&i`) on a local variable that goes out of scope (`i`) the instant `BuildFns()` returns.  A capture by reference may as well be a pointer and, as a local variable, likely a pointer to the stack in this instance.  As such, you shouldn't be surprised that the value randomly changes.  All it needs is for some mechanism in the `std::function` call to write to the stack, and then your value is gone.

If you actually want the value of `i` at the time of the creation of the closure, do a capture by value instead.